# LOGCAT comprehension in ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: android

I have a `Logcat error report` that i am not being able to comprehend. Can you please help me out? I am new to Android application development!

```
07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=26; index=26

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.example.hangman.Play$1.onClick(Play.java:70)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

07-10 08:51:42.603: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my OnClickListener() code is below:
                View.OnClickListener go_func = new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int flag = 0;
        TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        TextView chances = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chances);
        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.word);
        EditText guessed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter_guessed);
        String letter = guessed.getText().toString();
        char[] Letter = letter.toCharArray();
        String current_status = status.getText().toString();
        String current_chances = chances.getText().toString();
        String current_word = new String(); 

        //checking if letter is already guessed
        for(int i=0;i<letters_guessed.length;i++)
        {
            if(Letter[0] == letters_guessed[i])
            {
                current_status = "Letter Already Guessed!";
                status.setText(current_status);
            }
            break;
        }

        //if letter is not already guessed
        if(current_status !="Letter Already Guessed!")
        {
            int len=0;
            int i=0;
            while(letters_guessed[i] != '\u0000')
            {
                len++;
                i++;
            }
            if(len !=0)
                letters_guessed[len] = Letter[0];
            else
                letters_guessed[0] = Letter[0];

            for(i=0;i<word_chosen.length();i++)
            {   
                flag = 0;
                for(int j=0;j<letters_guessed.length;j++)
                {

                    if(word_final[i]==letters_guessed[j])
                    {
                        char[] temp_array = current_word.toCharArray();
                        temp_array[temp_array.length] = word_final[i];
                        current_word = temp_array.toString();
                        flag=1;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    char[] temp_array = current_word.toCharArray();
                    temp_array[temp_array.length] = '_';
                    current_word = temp_array.toString();
                }

            }
        }
        int a=0;
        char[] word_check = word_chosen.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<word_check.length;i++)
        {
            if(word_check[i] == Letter[0])
            {
                a=1;
                status.setText("Correct guess!");
            }
        }
        if(a==0)
        {
            status.setText("Wrong guess!");
        } 
        word.setText(current_word);

    }
};
```

Comment: seriously terrible subject i must say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogCat shows at which point in the different classes of your Application were executing when the crash happened:

Top line shows that you have `FATAL Exception` due to the next line `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (You are trying to access item 26 in an Array whose size is 26, as numbering is from 0-25)

Next, this exception was caused when your application was executing line 70 in `onClick()` method inside your `com.example.hangman.Play Activity`:

```
at com.example.hangman.Play$1.onClick(Play.java:70)
```

The remaining lines are the rest of the classes that are run by Android system (and were executing when the crash happened) to perform `onClick()` internally.

So to sum up, you are having `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `line 70` in your `onClick()` method in `Play` Activity

Comment: Can't see line numbers here, but I'm guessing that letters_guessed is empty.

Comment: Initially it is empty. I fill it up as the app goes on. Any problem related to this?

Comment: Which line is line 70 in you Play class?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException tells that you use wrong index when accessing array.
Your array size is 26 and index should be from 0 to 25.

change this

```
while(letters_guessed[i] != '\u0000')
        {
            len++;
            i++;
        }
```

to

```
while(i < letters_guessed.length - 1 && letters_guessed[i] != '\u0000')
        {
            len++;
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: That is the only one that i could understand! But in my program, the code only goes through proper indexing!

Comment: You need add checking for max i in while loop: 

   while(i < letters_guessed.length && letters_guessed[i] != '\u0000')
            {
                len++;
                i++;
            }

Comment: You could always purposefully use the logs to output debug values, such as `Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Length of letters_guessed is " + letters_guessed.length)`

Answer (score 0):

To help you resolve your own problems in the future (not just this one), it's helpful to understand how to purposefully use the Android Logger. There is a good resource [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to find out how this is done with the different types of information that you want to log.

What I would do if you can't easily find the problem at a glance, is to use the Logger purposefully to find out where you may be getting unexpected results. For example:

```
//checking if letter is already guessed
Log.d("Play", "letters_guessed.length = " + letters_guessed.length);
for(int i=0;i<letters_guessed.length;i++)
{
    Log.d("Play", "i = " + i);
    Log.d("Play", "Letter[0] = " + Letter[0]);
    if(Letter[0] == letters_guessed[i])
    {
        current_status = "Letter Already Guessed!";
        status.setText(current_status);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: actually what does Log do? What does Log.(something) mean?

Comment: If you're developing with Eclipse, you can view the log entries in real-time with the LogCat view. "Window --> Show View --> Other... --> Android --> LogCat". The "d" in Log.d just stands for "debug". There's also "i" for "info", "e" for "error", etc. The link I provided will give you more information on this.